# rights protected photo on iphone

Tags: iphone

I've been tasked with writing an iphone application that displays a set of images (think powerpoint slideshow).  The content of these images need to be protected from forwarding

this task seems quite simple with one exception - I'd like to prevent the user from taking a screenshot

it's not like i'm protecting the crown jewels here, so I'm not looking for military grade super ninja protection.  but on the iphone it's so common and easy to take a snapshot...

thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I disable screenshots on iphone or automatically watermark image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492798/how-do-i-disable-screenshots-on-iphone-or-automatically-watermark-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prevent a screenshot, and AFAIK you won't be notified that it is about to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You have absolutely no control with the public SDK to prevent the user from taking a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Just stick a copyright notice or warning on the display.  Even if you could somehow protect against the double button screenshot, that would be of no help against someone taking a photo of one iPhone's display using another iPhone, etc.