# iOS7 Screen Capture Prevention / Detection

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, screenshot

In my iOS app I need either prevent the screenshot capture (by pressing combination of Home +Power button), or need to detect before it saved to the Photo library .
In previous iOS version before taking screenshot `touchesCancelled:withEvent` this method will called , but iOS7 onwards this wont work.
Apple provide a notification

```
 UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification
```

for detecting screenshot capture .The real problem is this will fire only after the screenshot is saved in Photo library .

Is there any methods (Private /Public) for detecting screenshot before it happens , or Just prevent the screenshot feature .

**Dont consider it as a duplicate question , it is iOS7 specific question**

Comment: @QED this is not a duplicate one , the question you are mentioned was asked years ago , that time there is a solution for this , now iOS7 came and the solution wont work , consider this as a iOS7 specific question

Comment: Actually, I'm regretting the retraction...

Comment: I dont know why some one did "This question may already have an answer here:" above my question , The link mentioned there is asked and answered years ago ,and that time there is a solutions .

Comment: It has been asked and answered *many* times out there… because it's a very good question. But I think you've got your answer… good luck!

Comment: But the answer mentioned is just for the device specific , I am looking for app specific , And no one asked about Private API support for this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42389/discussion-between-qed-and-rajesh)

Answer (score 2):

No, nothing has changed since iOS7 and it will not change in the future, it is a conceptual issue, iOS app doesn't has control over the device public functions, consider you turned off 'taking screenshot' while other application needs it!! How this app would know about that?

Best thing you can do is using Configuration Profile as mentioned @QED valid answer.

Comment: I am also looking for any private API available , it is not an Appstore app.So looking forwards for more ideas

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict with a Configuration Profile, as described in the linked question.

Check out the *Restrictions Payload* section, starting on page 27, of the [iPhone Configuration Proifile Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef.pdf). The key you want is `allowScreenShot`, described at the bottom of page 30.

Also, the linked reference states that there are a number of ways to install a profile. It may be possible for you to provide, within the app, some method for the user to trigger your server to install/reinstall your profile. Just a thought, I'm not experienced in the matter.

I'm not able to speak to private APIs. You might check out http://www.modmyi.com, or snoop around on IRC for some jailbreak communities. There are lots of experts out there who may be able to point you to the API, but they don't tend to hang on SO.

Good luck!

Comment: This is also a way to do this , even if it is not programmatic  method  .Thanks @QED

Comment: My impression is that this is the *only* way.

Comment: This will just disable the screenshot feature for device , I am looking for an app specific solution