# Is it possible to detect if a user takes a screenshot in iOS?

Tags: ios, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notification of or detecting screenshot being taken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121970/notification-of-or-detecting-screenshot-being-taken)

Since it's not possible to prevent someone from taking a screenshot, is there a way to detect it?

Comment: Listen to the microphone for the click.  Won't work on an iPod Touch, though.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I think it was a good solution for the devices with sdk < 4.0 installed. Tried on my iPad with 4.3.2 - does not work.