# ios perform method when user took a screenshot/photo

Tags: ios, background, fetch

Hi I press the home button then my app is in the background. Can I perform a method in my app when the user took screenshot? In google plus, it seems that the autoupload works when you click the app again not after you took a photo. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to detect if a user is pressing the screen capture buttons on iOS??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097617/possible-to-detect-if-a-user-is-pressing-the-screen-capture-buttons-on-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be notified when the user has taken a screenshot by listening for the notification:

```
UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification
```

Apple Reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification can we use this while the app is in the background? And if the app receives this notification, can it upload while on the background?

Comment: @Jen No, I don't believe you'll get this notification if you're not the foreground app, though I've never tried. Try it out for yourself, shouldn't take but a moment. Regarding uploading in the background, it's possible to start an upload when you're in the foreground and continue once you've been backgrounded: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788106/continue-uploading-process-in-background-ios

Comment: Yeah thats what i think too. Just thought that someone might have done this already haha. Thanks ksimons!

Comment: By the way, can we use push notifications or a server to tell our app to upload something while it is running in the background?