# iPhone: screenshot

Tags: iphone

Is there any method that calls in app when user made screenshot (hold home button + power) ???
Or which methods could be called ? Like applicationDidBecomeActive or something else ? Thanks...

Comment: This is a legitimate question, and it shouldn't have been "closed as not a real question". If anything, it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

You could periodically check the latest photo in the library using code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867496/get-last-image-from-photos-app).

Then check some properties to see if it is NOT coming from the camera or other source:

- the format should be PNG
- dimensions should match the screen size
- some additional metadata, perhaps

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 4.0, there was a notification fired `PictureWasTakenNotification`, but not anymore in iOS 5.0 or latter.

Comment: I have seen apps that detect this; I assume they detect its addition to the asset library in some way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2121970/602011

Comment: In iOS 4.0, there was a Darwin notification fired PictureWasTakenNotification, but not anymore.