# iOS - block screenshot/watermak

Tags: ios

Is it possible to block screenshots (Power + menu buttons) of an app?
If not, would be possible that this screenshot receives a watermark?

Regards,
Claudio

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notification of or detecting screenshot being taken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121970/notification-of-or-detecting-screenshot-being-taken)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notification of or detecting screenshot before being taken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121970/notification-of-or-detecting-screenshot-before-being-taken)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creation of screenshot is a system behavior and you cannot override it.

Duplicate of [Notification of or detecting screenshot being taken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121970/notification-of-or-detecting-screenshot-being-taken)

Comment: I've just found this question, I will delete this one. Thanks a lot!