# How to detect press the home button and lock button simultaneously in iOS?

Tags: ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notification of or detecting screenshot being taken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121970/notification-of-or-detecting-screenshot-being-taken)

Currently, I realize that you can't not caught home and lock button simultaneously in iOS app?
If my conclusion is wrong, please point at to me how to detect this event.

Thanks,

Comment: You must be able to, snap chat figured it out.

Comment: @0x7fffffff Snap Chat does it by detecting the touches cancelled event...it will only work if the user does it while touching the screen

Comment: @borrrden Hmm, interesting. Wouldn't that open the door for a lot of false positives?

Comment: @0x7fffffff Indeed it would, see this blog -> http://blog.chpwn.com/post/38491252231

Comment: @borrrden your blog.chpwn.com/post/38491252231 link has no content. Do you have any alternative solution? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Tulon I think this is the same post -> http://blog.chpwn.com/post/154128330241/how-to-detect-screenshots-on-ios-like-snapchat

Comment: @borrrden, ok Thanks mate.

Comment: if you want to detect screenshot use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50981934/6716574

Answer (score 1):

Your app delegate method `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application`
 will be called when the user takes a screenshot.  If you want to emulate SnapChat then just hide your window in this method (be sure to unhide it in `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`)

Comment: "Your app delegate method - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application will be called when the user takes a screenshot" -> I checked and delegate method wasn't called when user takes a screenshot. I have a solution based on borrrden guide.